# Find the interval of convergence for the Taylor series approximation of $f(x) = \ln(x + 3)$ about $x = 1$

Tags: convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

I managed to determine the Taylor series for the function and got
$$\log(x+3) = \log4 + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \frac{(-1)^n(x-1)^{n+1}}{(4^{n+1})(n+1)}$$

But how do I find its interval of convergence? If the $\log4$ term wasn't there, I would know how to do it by applying ratio test but with the $\log4$, I don't understand how to apply the test.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: 1) Don't bother about $\log4.$ The interval of convergence is the same with as without it. 2) It is not $\sum_{i=0}^n$ but $\sum_{n=0}^\infty$.

Comment: Yeah, I pasted the code and forgot to edit that portion. So I applied the ratio test and now have - 3< x<5. Would the log4 not change the interval at all?

Comment: Note that $\ln(x+3)$ turns south for $x=-3$ 

Therefore starting from $x_0=1$ you can expect the radius of convergence to be $4$ because $x_0-4=-3$ is critical.

Answer (score 1):

If the $\log 4$ term is creating problems for you, simply shift it to the left.  The interval of convergence will be the same even without it.

Apply the ratio test on the expression obtained after subtracting $\log 4$ as usual.

You will observe that the radius of convergence will turn out to be $4$, since the absolute value of the term $\dfrac{x-1}{4}$ should be less than 1.